# cucumber-js: Prevent attachments swamping output

Tags: bdd, attachment, cucumberjs

When working with web applications, in the event of a failed scenario, I sometimes want to record the HTML in my browser's body, along with a few other bits and pieces gathered using javascript to help diagnose what went wrong.

I usually do this by `executeScript` and grabbing `document.body.outerHTML`. I then attach the diagnostics using:

`await this.attach( JSON.stringify( diagnostics ), "text/plain" );`

This works great, but has the unfortunate side effect of dumping the attachment out when running the scenario with default runners (like the `progress` runner: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/attachments.md#readme )

How can I attach diagnostics like this (which are primarily for use in continuous pipeline runs) without them swamping my terminal output?

Answer (score 0):

Granted I have not tested this myself but according to the documentation if you provide a path with the output formatter(in your case progress) then the output will be to a file instead of `stdout`

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#formats
See the above docs for more info ^

Comment: That's true but then you lose _all_ output to the file - not just the diagnostics stuff?

Comment: @goofballLogic Yes I tested it out and you are correct. I don't believe there is any existing functionality for it. Sounds like it could be a feature request. I will try find some time to jump into the cucumber-js code and see where it get's attached and make it an optional action.

Comment: I believe this is where it gets attached https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/src/formatter/helpers/issue_helpers.js#L108. I won't have time this week to attempt adding a settings check but you should try it yourself and make a PR to the repo. If not I can look into it next week.

Answer (score 0):

Without any built-in support (yet) for fine-grained control of attachment output, I'm working around this issue by attaching the output using a custom content type. Anything other than text/plain isn't automatically output.